# Pass crystal report object to Report Document not physical file

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

How can I pass crystal report class name to ReportDocument dynamically.

E.g.

```
ReportDocument rpt;
rpt = new ReportDocument();
rpt.Load(filepath);
```

but I need to use

```
ReportDocument rpt;
rpt = new CrystalReport1(); // CrystalReport1 is report name
```

But I need to pass "CrystalReport1" as dynamically, so dynamically it create Report object. How can I do that ?

Comment: How is your `CrystalReport1` class defined?

Comment: @YannickBlondeau please check "CrystalReport1.cs" files code.. it as " public class CrystalReport1: ReportClass"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the answer by my own , please check below..

```
CrystalReport obj = new CrystalReport();
ReportDocument rpt = (ReportDocument)obj;
```